# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Evaluate:$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Evaluate:$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds$.

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t}f(s)ds+\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h}f(s)ds$.

Intuitively, I know that these both limit tends to $f(t)$. Therefore answer will be $2f(t)$.

But I don't know the formal way to prove that this limit tends to $2f(t)$. Help me if there is any formal proof of this (like using any theorem etc.)

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Hint: use MVT $\\\\\\$

Comment: I tried to solve using fundamental theorem of calculus by defining function $g(h)=\int_{t-h}^{t}f(s)ds$.I then differentiate $g$.But I did not get what to do next

Comment: @ahmed,Which MVT,MVT of integration or MVT of differentiation?

Comment: For integrals. $\\\\\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds =(t+h-(t-h))f(c_h), c_h\in [t-h,t+h]$ thus $1/h\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds =2f(c_h)$ and the limit is $2f(t)$ since $f$ is continue

Comment: For those keeping score:  (1) This solution uses the so-called *first mean-value theorem for integrals* which requires continuity on an interval.  (2)  The other solution suggested uses the fundamental theorem of the calculus which would require only integrability on an interval and continuity at the one point.  (3)  Another solution would use continuity at the one point to find an interval $(s-\delta,s+\delta)$ on which $f(t)-\epsilon<f(s)<f(t)+\epsilon$ and then standard inequalities with integrals.  Anyone know a fourth (different) solution?

Comment: The third solution is really just a proof of the FTC.