# Let be $f$ a continuous function. Determine the limit $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{a-h}^{a+h} f(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{a-h}^{a+h} f(x)\,dx$

I think that this kind of limit should I probably calculate with some kind of epsilon-delta definition.

And using the limits:

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1}{h}=\infty $

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0^-} \frac{1}{h}=-\infty $

I appreciate any helps.

Comment: You may want to use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: [First fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). And, perhaps, Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Comment: Duplicate: [Let be $f$ a continuous function. Determine the limit $\displaystyle\smash{\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{a-h}^{a+h} \!\!\!f(x)\,dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529506/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bh%20%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bh%7D%20%5Cint_%7Ba-h%7D%5E%7Ba%2Bh%7D%20f(x)%5C%2Cdx%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using L'Hospital's rule we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x) \,dx}{h} &= 
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)}{1} \\
&= 2f(a).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Note $f$ has an antiderivative, $F$. Thus $\int_{a-h}^{a+h} f(t) \ dt = F(a+h) - F(a-h)$ and so we're evaluating

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(a+h) - F(a-h)}{h} = 2\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(a+h) - F(a-h)}{2h} = 2F'(a) = 2f(a)$$

Note that the second-to-last equality follows from the fact that if the derivative of a function exists, its [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) exists and is equal to it.

Comment: Can you maybe explain it without using symmetric derivative? It's a really new area for me, thanks for your previous answer.

Comment: @Zauberkerl $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(a+h) - F(a-h)}{2h} = \frac 12 \left(\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(a) - F(a-h)}{h}\right) = \frac 12 \left(\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(a+h) - F(a)}{h} + \lim_{u \to a}\frac{F(a) - F(u)}{a-u}\right) = 2F'(a)$$

We substituted $a-h = u$ in the last step.

Comment: typo: the above comment should just have $F'(a)$ at the end

Answer (score 1):

I will first prove for $h\rightarrow 0^{+}$, for $h\rightarrow 0^{-}$ is treated simialrly. As $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, given $\epsilon>0$, one may find some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ for every $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. For all $h\in(0,\delta)$, we have

$\left|\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)dx-2f(a)\right|\\
=\left|\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(x)dx-\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{a-h}^{a+h}f(a)dx\right|\\
\leq\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{a-h}^{a+h}|f(x)-f(a)|dx\\
\leq\dfrac{1}{h}\displaystyle\int_{a-h}^{a+h}\epsilon dx\\
=2\epsilon$.

So the limit is $2f(a)$.